# Flask where to read csv data for use in views

Tags: python, flask

I'm wondering where the read_csv method should live, in order for it to be accessible by the views in flask, and for optimum unit testing. Ideally for unit tests, I assume I wouldn't want to read the CSV data, so it should be easily mockable?

I'm currently importing data after creating the application, before the views. The views are then accessing the dataframe. Should this be handled elsewhere?

Currently set up like:

```
application = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# views below...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the csv file inside a route, when get method will be called the route will read the csv and render the output.